# Monitor mode with TL-WN725N and 4.19.0 kernel

Tags: linux, drivers, kali-linux, wireless-adapter

I'd like to use monitor mode and packet injection on my Kali linux VM running 4.19.0-kali5-amd64 kernel. I'm using a TP-Link WN725N v2 USB adapter (RTL8188EUS chip) and the default r8188eu driver doesn't allow it.

After googling a bit, I found [this driver](https://github.com/quickreflex/rtl8188eus). After cloning the 5.2.2.4 branch, I ran `make` and `make install` without issues (the new driver is `8188eu.ko)`.
The problem is, after running `lsusb -t`, the old `r8188eu` is still used, even if the newly compiled 8188eu is loaded :

```
# lsmod
Module        Size   Used by
8188eu     1830912   0
r8188eu     487424   0
lib80211     16384   1 r8188eu
cfg80211    761856   2 8188eu,r8188eu
...            ...   ...
```

So, how can I get the new driver to work with my adapter ? Did I do something wrong at compile time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of the aircrack-ng rtl8188eus driver.

You have 2 versions of the same driver loaded. That doesn't work.

- r8188eu is lwfinger's standalone driver (a bit old too) which comes with kernels upstream
- 8188eu is our (aircrack-ng) and also newer then the other. The driver has monitor mode, frame injection, MESH support etc. See [README.md](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus/blob/v5.3.9/README.md).

According to our README.md, you need to blacklist the older "standalone" driver (by lwfinger) by adding a `.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d` (e.g: `echo r8188eu > /etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf`) and then reboot in order to unload/blacklist it (or `modprobe -r 8188eu`)

Our drivers support a wide range of kernels and are heavily maintained. As of now, it supports the latest, v5.3+.

Answer (score -1):

I make a video in this topic.
https://youtu.be/c4L1sSJzer8
Check this video.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to make a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). You should write down the most important points, and leave the video link as "for more detailed info please see". Answers only provide an external link are considered low quality, and [get deleted](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers). Also note that low-quality answers will lead to [answer ban](https://superuser.com/help/answer-bans). In general it's a good idea to have a read through the Help section of a new community, as the rules vary per community.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1081729)